# Mysql 5.5.25 must be restarted to connect

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, windows

We have MySQL v5.5.25 running on Windows Server 2008 R2. Occasionally people are unable to connect, and the only way we have found to fix this is to restart the mysql service. This happens every 2-3 days.

Anyone have a clue on this? We have spent hours trying to fix it changing various values in the configuration, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Have you looked in the log files? Difficult to help without anything more specific.

Comment: There is nothing in the general logfile related to this. But i can add that when the problem occurs, we can still connect using MySQL Workbench. We have some vb6 direct.dll integration and it seems that is the one failing. Are there any known bugs in that area?

Comment: Any sort of error message, from the application, perhaps?  Setting `log_warnings` = 2 in config may increase the likelihood of getting some logging to explain failed connections.  This goes to the error log, as opposed to the general log.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind what the MySQL Documentation says about [max_connect_errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors)

> If more than this many successive connection requests from a host are interrupted without a successful connection, the server blocks that host from further connections. You can unblock blocked hosts by flushing the host cache. To do so, issue a FLUSH HOSTS statement or execute a mysqladmin flush-hosts command. If a connection is established successfully within fewer than max_connect_errors attempts after a previous connection was interrupted, the error count for the host is cleared to zero. However, once a host is blocked, flushing the host cache is the only way to unblock it.

MySQL 5.5's default value for `max_connect_errors` is 10.

I have two suggestions on resetting the connection error count errors besides restarting mysql:

## SUGGESTION #1

Create a one line SQL script (such as `C:\FlushHosts.sql`)

Setup a scheduled task to execute `mysql -uroot < C:\FlushHosts.sql` every hour

## SUGGESTION #2

Goto my.ini and add the following line

```
[mysqld]
max_connect_errors=18446744073709547520
```

Then, login to mysql client and run this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors = 18446744073709547520;
```

After setting `max_connect_errors` this high, you should never get connection errors. Otherwise, you must running mysql in some parallel universe.

## Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the output of these queries:

`show full processlist`; and `show global status like 'max_used_connections';`

You can edit configuration file `my.ini` and increase `max_connections` value and give a try.